# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense freeze

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, intellisense

I try to write something in the .cs file, or in the .aspx file at a moment when the intellisesnse comes in, the environment freezes, not responding for a while, 30 to 60 sec.. witch is very annoying because i can't write my code.

This is happening when i write C# code, when i write html tags, when i write JQuery code.. 
I did the latest updates to VS ... SP1, i disabled advanced features for intellisense.. but still i can't fight this one :)

My configuration: Intel Dual Core, 4GB RAM, 1GB HD Video, Win7 64bit, VS2010 64bit SP1.
Any suggestions? thank you! This problem is killing me!

Comment: I use VS2010 daily and I can tell you, it's still pretty buggy at times.  Do you have any third party extensions installed?

Comment: i had, at the beginning i installed some features to help me write code more efficient but then i realized i have this problem, and i removed all installed extensions.

Comment: still having problems... nobody here had same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I re-installed Visual Studio. I took the Ultimate (latest) version this time, not the Pro, and all seems to be working fine.